# CakePHP is unwantedly encoding HTML entities in View output via ExceptionRenderer

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm attempting to create a custom 404 page in CakePHP 2.0 by extending ExceptionRenderer. Everything is working fine except when I output HTML marked-up strings in the View Cake is unwantedly encoding the HTML entities. How can I prevent this from happening?

In my renderer I have:-

```
class AppExceptionRenderer extends ExceptionRenderer {
    public function missingController($error) {
        $this->controller->set('test', '<p>Test</p>');
        header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');
        $this->controller->render('/Errors/error404', 'default');
        $this->controller->set('title_for_layout', 'Page Not Found');
        $this->controller->response->send();
    }
}
```

In the view (View/Error/error404.ctp):-

```
<?php echo $test ?>
```

This outputs `&lt;test&gt;` rather than `<p>test</p>`.

In my actual code `test` will be being set by content from the database as this is a CMS driven site. I'm just setting `test` in the renderer code above as an example (and to prove the code is behaving as I am observing).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't be using HTML inside your PHP, you should write any markup in the view file.

I've not come across a situation when you would need to write the markup inside your PHP code, but if you have no other way around it you could always use the [`html_entity_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) function inside your view.

Unfortunately I don't know a way to stop Cake from encoding it automatically like you want.

Comment: I completely agree that HTML does not belong in PHP. I am developing a CMS driven site that needs to retrieve this content from the database. I just put the $test variable in my code above as an example and to test that it wasn't being returned by the database as encoded. 

`html_entity_decode()` does work, but would like to know why Cake is doing this in the first place. This issue does not arise elsewhere in my app when I am setting variables in my controllers.